# Upgrading from vue 2.6 (composition api) to 2.7, issues with store and routes

Tags: vuejs2

I can't find any documentation on this.
Currently when I want to get an instance of the store or a route in 2.6 I do this:

```
import { ComponentInternalInstance, computed } from "@vue/composition-api";

const store = instance.proxy.$store;
const router = instance.proxy.$router;
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve the same in vue 2.7?

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 2.7.x, you can use it like this:

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const { proxy } = getCurrentInstance()
const router = proxy.$router
```

As it's discussed [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/3760#issuecomment-1178468293).